# Should I move client configuration data to the server?

Tags: configuration, client-server

I have a client software program used to launch alarms through a central server.  At first it stored configuration data in registry entries, now in a configuration XML file.  This configuration information consists of Alarm number, alarm group, hotkey combinations, and such.

This client connects to a server using a TCP socket, which it uses to communicate this configuration to the server.  In the next generation of this program, I'm considering moving all configuration information to the server, which stores all of its information in a SQL database.

I envision using some form of web interface to communicate with the server and setup the clients, rather than the current method, which is to either configure the client software on the machine through a control panel, or on install to ether push out an xml file, or pass command line parameters to the MSI.  I'm thinking now the only information I would want to specify on install would be the path to the server.  Each workstation would be identified by computer name, and configured through the server.

Are there any problems or potential drawbacks of this approach?  The main goal is to centralize configuration and make it easier to make changes later, because our software is usually managed by one or two people at most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than allowing for the client to function offline (if such a possibility makes sense for your application), there doesn't appear to be any drawback of moving the configuration to a centralized location.   Indeed even with a centralized location, a feature can be added in the client to cache the last known configuration, for use when the client is offline).

In case you implement a [centralized] database design, I suggest to consider storing configuration parameters in an Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) structure as this schema is particularly well suited for parameters.  In particular it allows easy addition and removal of particular parameters and also the handling parameters as a list (paving the way for a list-oriented display as well in the UI, and therefore no changes needed in the UI either when new types of parameters are introduced).

Another reason why configuartion parameter collections and  EAV schemas work well together is that even with very many users and configuration points, the configuration data remains small enough that is doesn't suffer some of the limitations of EAV with "big" tables.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that comes to mind is security of the information.  In either case you probably have that issue though. Probably be easier to interface with though with a database as everything would be in one spot.

Comment: Good point, as always, bringing in stuff centrally may expose privacy or security sensitive info which formally stayed locally on the client.